# Non-invocable member 'datagirdview.Rows' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

In my C# windows form, I have a column button, i want to onclick i get some specific columns of the gridview

Here is the code:

```
 private void attack_History_ViewDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            attack_History_ViewDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0);
        }
```

Unfortunatly, in word `Rows` it complains with:

```
Non-invocable member 'datagirdview.Rows' cannot be used like a method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the items of your row collection, you have to use the indexer, which is done with square brackets (`[]`). Same applies for `Cells`:

```
attack_History_ViewDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
```